# What is the correct way to post a colon in a querystring parameter?

Tags: html, forms, http-post

I am posting a form and one of the field values has a ":" and that is causing an issue

is there any correct way to be able to post this string;

```
 http://www.mysite.com/MyController/MyAction?field1=Japan:Tokyo&field2=USA:NewYork
```

Comment: Form data is automatically encoded correctly when you post a form. What does your code look like, as you don't appear to post the form in the regular way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use percent encoded version of colon `"%3A"`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of libraries will have a method to process this, for example in ASP.NET if you do a [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that should get changed to a `%3A`, when you need to use it just do a [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the string.

```
http://www.mysite.com/MyController/MyAction?field1=Japan%3ATokyo&field2=USA%3ANewYork
```

If you are not using any library that has this type of functionality then you can easily build your own little parsing function that will replace common characters with their [HTML character code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) equivalent.

Comment: if i am doing this on a form post, i assume i need to do this on the javascript side.  any suggestions on automatically doing this before a form post to protect agaginst this issue

Comment: @leora If you are using a Javascript library check whether it has this kind of functionality. If you're not then consider writing your own quick and dirty function to do it - there is no point using a library only to get URL encoding.